# Netsuite: How to add a column to each item on an order?

Tags: netsuite

We sell digital products that require us to collect additional information (a Host ID) in order to sell them.

How do I add a column to each item on our web store?

I tried going to Customization > Lists, Records & Fields > Transaction Item Options and created a new one and selected web store and applied it to all items, but nothing shows up anywhere in the checkout process.

Do I need to do something else/different?

Here's a screenshot of my setup: http://shopping.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=846414&c=3514567&h=7a7dd71da6be0fcc7faf

Answer (score 0):

These will just tend to show up on the item buy pages. If you've had significant customization done you may have to show them again. Do you have a publicly available item page that should show the field?

Comment: So there's no way to collect new item info in the checkout process? When I tested adding a transaction body field it showed up on the review order page, which is perfect.  My item page is completely customized: http://shop.controlco.com/Manufacturers/CSI3/DRV-DNP3-AX-J

Comment: the "Easy way" is to add `<%=getAddToCartOptions%>` to the page inside a hidden table. It looks like that would show up around line 1331 on your sample page. Then you'd use a script to pull any 'custcol' field info there up to the detail form. At least that's normally what I do. There are alternatives but they are more complex

Comment: To answer your original question though you could have your fields on the shopping cart or order checkout but you'd need a lot of customization.

Comment: Not working. I get: [Error processing dynamic tag getAddToCartOptions() : Unknown method getAddToCartOptions()]

Comment: Sorry `addtocartoptionshtml`
Note: Log in to Netsuite and go to https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N2634674.html

Comment: I can't tell if I'm just being obtuse or what...I added the following to the above link but the div is just blank <div id="options" style="display:hidden"><%=getCurrentAttribute('item','addtocartoptionshtml')%></div>  shop.controlco.com/Manufacturers/CSI3/DRV-DNP3-AX-J

Comment: An you attach a screen shot of your custom transaction column screen

Comment: It's not a transaction column. It's a Transaction Item Option. I will add a screenshot to the question above in a sec.

Comment: Sorry. Just mis-typed. Not misunderstood.
Saw your screen shot. As long as the display is set to normal that should work. How are your pages being generated? Is that from a normal sitebuilder template?

Comment: It's a site builder template (item drilldown), our own custom one (vs. one of the standard ones). We don't use options (we don't have colors, etc.) - each part has its own number, so I wonder if something else needs to be configured there. (?)

Comment: I assume you've used other getCurrentAttribute tags successfully on your pages. Is that the case? I don't know what else to suggest but a possible hack: turn on matrix items. see if the option shows up; then turn it off again and see if the option still works. Note if this is an apply to all situation you could use a custom transaction column instead of a custom item option. Or just try adding a custom transaction column as well as the custom item option and see what happens.